# 404 - Article not found when calling not Joomla php file

Tags: joomla-3.4, server, error-pages

I have a 3.4 Joomla site which works fine, the problem is I created a new directory to store some php scripts to run, but running them fails with the 404 error above.

Joomla runs on the root folder, let say /u01/public_html
and I created a directory /u01/public_html/test

I need to run http://mydomain.com/test and that's when I get the 404 error, even if I create a simple index.php file with just phpinfo(); in it fails.

I have played with the Joomla's .htaccess file but nothing, I even created another .htaccess in the test dir. and still nothing.

Can you please let me know how can I let Joomla know that the test directory should NOT be managed by Joomla ?

What entries should I put in the .htaccess files so that I can run the scripts in the test dir?

Thanks,

Cesar

Comment: Please check the permission assign to that folder

Comment: Just for the records: Most filesystems are case sensitive. So server.com/test and server.com/Test ain't the same.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you reach directly to another custom directory/files, Joomla is not involved - so actually there is nothing you should tell to Joomla regarding any other custom directories you are creating.

The 404 error you are getting when trying to reach at your test folder, means that the test folder/files do not exist in this location and this isn't generated because of Joomla.

Normally you won't have to make any adjustments in the htaccess file - unless if you have previously added certain restrictions.

But again the error you are getting is 404 and not something else, so make sure you are reaching at a file that exists at the specified location.

Now I don't know if you have any other special configurations or any kind of extensions that could change the normal behavior in your site - if so let us know about.